# Mac Pro was working fine. Formatted the hard drives and now the monitor can't get a picture

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, boot, troubleshooting

My mac computer was working fine but I took the hard drives out of it and formatted them with my new computer. Now when I re-insert the zero-filled drives the monitor is just perpetually black.

I tried using the original graphics card that came with the Mac Pro (8800 GT) but that didn't work (even though I know the card works) and even tried another graphics card I know works but that didn't work either.

I took out all drives but the first one, all ram but 2 sticks, and even tried other monitors that I know worked. Nothing.

I tried resetting the NVRAM, holding option during boot, apple hardware test, and booting from the CD. No picture on the monitor for any of those attempts.

I know the computer works because it was working fine before I formatted the drives. Also it responds to keyboard input like holding F12 during bootup opens the tray and holding command option p r I can hear the mac chime twice.

The only thing I can think of is maybe the bootloader is screwed up. Like 5 years ago when trying to set up a tri-boot I was messing with the bootloader. If this is the case is there any way to fix it? Where is the bootloader stored? Can it be reset?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I'm really not sure how serious this question is. But assuming it is serious, you're going to want to reinstall Mac OSX by booting from your OS CD.

Comment: Which is to say:  Yes.  The bootloader's screwed up.  Specifically, it's *gone*.  Just like the copy of OSX that was there before.  That's what *happens* when one zeroes out the hard drives.  Reinstall OSX.

Answer (score 1):

Both the bootloader and the OS are generally stored on the hard drive.  If thou hast zeroed all the hard drives in the machine, thou wilt need to reinstall OSX - Hopefully thou hast an install disc lying around somewhere.